# Posting New html from TINYMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Seems like a simple problem, I have a form and when someone needs to edit data, the textarea that is controlled by TINYMCE loads the values, but when I change it and submit the form, the new changes are not being posted.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
How do I do it via this, or do it say on click in the editor.  I am using jquery validate, this is the submit handler.

```
$(form).ajaxSubmit({
                target:'#result',
                success:function(){

                    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:'90px'}, 500);},
                clearForm: false});

                }});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to call tinyMCE's save method when the user clicks the submit button:

```
$(form).ajaxSubmit({
    beforeSerialize: function() {
        tinyMCE.get('content').save();  // 'content' is the id of your textarea
    },

    ...
});
```

Reference: http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:API/tinymce.Editor/save

Comment: Makes sense, I am using jquery to validate it with ajaxsubmit. How do you call it with the api? I'm not very good in using api's. Thank you

Comment: That works as a separate button, I tried putting that line in the beforeSubmit of the ajax post but that doesn't work. Is there another spot to place it so it can be 1 button, that validates, then submit's the form?? Thanks for the help so far, almost got it

Comment: Try beforeSerialize instead of beforeSubmit.